# Using ref on onClick that scrolls to a section instead of redirect with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

Currently I have a snippet in Component A like so - redirect with props:

```
<MyBanner
  onClick={() => history.push("/user/dashboard", "mySection")}
/>;
```

In `"/user/dashboard"` Dashboard component (Component B) - In this component, I check for these 'redirect' props. If there is one, call a `scrollIntoView` function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const view = location.state;
    const mySectionId = document.getElementById("mySection");

    if (view) {
        mySectionId?.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth",
        });
    }
});

<div id={"mySection"}> ..... </div>
```

Currently, I'm manipulating the DOM directly which is not a React way.
How can I do this the `React` way by using refs?

Answer (score 0):

Like the [original documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref), just refer to the element you want to manipulate:

```
const mySectionId = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    const view = location.state;
    if (view) {
        mySectionId.current?.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth",
        });
    }
});

<div ref={mySectionId} id={"mySection"}> ..... </div>
```

Comment: You also need to access `mySectionId.current` and probably add an empty dependency array so it only runs on the first render.